# AppleTV: implementing launch screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, tvos, apple-tv

I'm working on AppleTV implementation but I need to implement an launch screen. In the AppleTV project in Xcode doesn't give you this options:

[image]

Any of you knows a way to implement the launch screen ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: I suspect that you may still be on Xcode 7.1 beta; Install the GM.

Comment: Do you need a dynamic image withe the xib file or just an image?

Comment: @Stefan I want to implement a presentation like you can in iOS in the LaunchScreen.xib.

Comment: Launch images are newly obsolete. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162971/can-storyboards-be-used-as-the-launch-screen-in-tvos currently applies.

Comment: Up to date solution (launch images are deprecated)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162971/can-storyboards-be-used-as-the-launch-screen-in-tvos

Answer (score 0):

Go to the asset catalog of your app and add a launch image (if not already added automatically:

[image]

Select the launch image:

[image]