# Can storyboards be used as the launch screen in tvos?

Tags: ios, xcode, tvos

In iOS, storyboards can be used as the launch screen instead of static images. I am looking for a way to do this with tvOS as well, but I don't see the option. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Launch images have been deprecated in tvOS 13.0. Now we have to use launch storyboards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now use storyboards, in fact as of tvOS 13.0 it's the preferred method.

It will automatically be set up for you on new projects. For old projects create your launch image story board, make sure "Is initial view controller" is checked in the inspector window. After setting up your storyboard under "**Project Setting -> General -> Launch Screen File**" you will be able to select your storyboard as the launch file to use.

Comment: Things have changed in the meantime. Starting with tvOS 13.1 using launch images is deprecated and you should use  a Storyboard or XIB. Checkout my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59754352/2961609

Answer (score 11):

**Solution for tvOS 13.1 and better**

Starting with tvOS 13.1 using launch images is deprecated.

The following build warning will appear:

> MyApp.xcassets:1:1: Launch images are deprecated in tvOS 13.0. Use a
>   launch storyboard or XIB instead.

You need to create a new storyboard in Xcode following this steps:

1. From Xcode main menu choose "File" -> "New" -> "File"
2. Change to the tvOS Tab and select "Storyboard" - name it "LaunchScreen.storyboard"
3. Open the new file "LaunchScreen.storyboard"
4. From Xcode main menu choose "View" -> "ShowLibrary"
5. Enter "View Controller" in the search bar and select the "ViewController" component
6. Done. Now you can design your launch screen in the view controllers view
7. Now select your project file in Xcode and then select the target of yout tvOS app
8. Make sure "General" is selected in the header
9. Change to the section "App icons and Launch Images"
10. In the drop down box "Launch Screen File" select ""LaunchScreen"
11. Build and run your app
12. Enjoy your new LaunchScreen

If your launch screen storyboard does not show up on app startup make sure that you've set the "InitalViewController" flag for the view controller in your storyboard:
[image]

Comment: I have followed the above steps but launchScreen didn't appear, i tried in sample project it works there. I have crossed check multiple times. Everything seems to be clear. Don't know what is the issue.. Please help. Thanks in advance.